# Cancel button redirect not working

Tags: php, mysql, validation

Inside my *readMore.php* page I have `add_comment.php` when user submits comment its redirects him to `readMore.php` according to dynamic id I used in query string.The adding comment works perfectly and user redirected in accordance, however while at the `add_comment.php` user clicks on cancel (if he doesnt want to leave a comment) its redirects him to my main blog page with all posts.
I used  `onclick="window.location='readMore.php?id=$post_id'"`. My `$post_id`holds the dynamic id of the post .

```
$post_id  = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
$post_id  = trim( $post_id );
```

Anyway its not working. 
Please advise

Comment: You're going to need to define *"Not working"*; check for errors (and the console) then tell us what they were. Your question doesn't contain enough code, such as the html for it also.

Comment: `window.location.href=`

Comment: there's also no mysql here

Comment: @Fred -ii- n user leaves comment he redirected back to readMore.php post on which he commented but if he wants to leave a comment and regrets and clicks cancel he is not redirected back to readMore.php of the same post but he redirected to blog page with all posts